# How to unwrap a text in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I found this macro to unwrap but it unwrap all the document instead of just the selected text. How can I modify it to unwrap only the selected text?

```
 Sub pagebreaks()
'
' pagebreaks Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "|"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p"
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "|"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

"Find and Replace" can search for the newline character (looks like a backwards double "P" kind of. Like [image]), and only replace all those with nothing. Only going through a selection of text should work? No macro required.

- [Find and replace text and other data in a Word document](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7?ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA)

> Use the following codes to find letters, formatting, fields, or
>   special characters. Note that some codes work only if the Use
>   wildcards option is turned on or off.
>
> Codes that work in the Find what box or Replace with box
>
> To find:
>   Paragraph mark ([image: Paragraph mark])
>
> Type:
>   ^p
>   (doesn't work in the Find what box when the Use wildcards option is
>   turned on),
>
> or type:
>   ^13

Or Find repeatedly & then delete (with delete key), only through a selection of text?

Comment: any idea how to replace several ^p by one? (replace ^p^p with ^p doesn't work)

Comment: solution using wildcard: FIND ([!.])^0013 REPLACE ^p then follow the answer

Comment: No ideas, reminds me of [`uniq`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl_uniq.htm) though.

Comment: any idea to unwrap only normal text (not the titles)? (The intuitive solution to select only the normal text doesn't work).

Comment: I'm using LibreOffice now, it's Writer has a  "Current selection only" checkbox in it's Find & Replace that implements your intuitive solution, but not sure about Word

Answer (score 1):

Here is what a macro that works:

```
  Sub pagebreaks()
    '
    ' pagebreaks Macro
    '
    '


With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "^p^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "|"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p"
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

With Selection.Find
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = "|"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

With Selection.Find
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```